# Display PHAssets on an MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, photosframework

I’d like to display the contents of a `PHAssetCollection` on an `MKMapView`.

My initial plan was:

- get the current region of the `MKMapView`
- write an `NSPredicate` to find the `PHAssets` that have a non-nil `location` value
- display those on the map using annotations.

Unfortunately, developers are disallowed from using `NSPredicate` to inspect the `location` property of a `PHAsset` - I’m guessing this is for performance or possibly privacy reasons - so I’m curious what I ought to try next for displaying these assets on a map.

One workaround that I’m considering: enumerate through the `PHAssetCollection` and build a cache of the assets with their locations, for displaying/clustering on the map.

I’d like to avoid building and updating a cache (though I feel that’s probably what’s required here) - I’d prefer to rely on a built-in `PHFetchResult<PHAsset>`.

If you’ve written code that displays a `PHAssetCollection` on a map, I’m curious how you implemented it!